# Binding Combobox to XML (wpf)

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, combobox

```
<EssenceList>
  <Essence GUID="464">
    <Properties>
      <Property Name="Name">
        <value>mt-1232-1. (1-1-3)</value>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Characteristics>
      <Characteristic GUID="78">
        <value>gadget</value>
      </Characteristic>
      <Characteristic GUID="79">
        <value>measures</value>
      </Characteristic>
    </Characteristics>
    <LinkedEssences>
      <LinkType Type="ObjGroup">
        <LinkedEssence GUID="369" />
      </LinkType>
      <LinkType Type="ObjGroupProp" />
      <LinkType Type="RoleObject">
            <LinkedEssence GUID="5747"/>
      </LinkType>
    </LinkedEssences>
  </Essence>
...
  <Essence GUID="5747" Type="Role">
    <Properties>
      <Property Name="Name">
        <value>UKPG-22</value>
      </Property>
      <Property Name="TagPrefix">
        <value>UKPG22</value>
      </Property>
      <Property Name="useParentTagPrefix">
        <value>0</value>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Essence>
...
  <Essence GUID="5748" Type="Role">
  </Essence>
...
```

in example is a xml file with data from database. now i need to bind it to some fields...
i use the XMLDataProvider here

```
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="dataxml" XPath="EssenceList/Essence" Source="464.xml"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
```

and mostof simple texboxes i bind like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=/EssenceList/Essence/LinkedEssences/LinkType[1]/LinkedEssence/@GUID}" />
```

but now i need to bind a combobox this way:
- the first Essence in the document contains LinkedEssences, that contains `<LinkType Type="RoleObject">` and `<LinkedEssence GUID="5747"/>`
- in document below there is a full description for it that contains the NAME property i need

```
  <Essence GUID="5747" Type="Role">
    <Properties>
      <Property Name="Name">
        <value>UKPG-22</value>
      </Property>
      <Property Name="TagPrefix">
        <value>UKPG22</value>
      </Property>
      <Property Name="useParentTagPrefix">
        <value>0</value>
      </Property>
    </Properties>
  </Essence>
```

and many other available Essences for this combobox

i managed to bind the list of thems to combobox

```
 <ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource rolelistTemplate}"  ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/EssenceList/Essence[@Type]}" />
```

so it displays it well, but i can't bind it to my LinkedEssences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've solved the problem simply by this

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="@GUID" SelectedValue="{Binding XPath=/EssenceList/Essence[1]/LinkedEssences/LinkType[3]/LinkedEssence[1]/@GUID}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource rolelistTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=/EssenceList/Essence[@Type]}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

so i just set SelectedValuePath to an attribute and SelectedValue to the field i need to save it)